# Keras LSTM Multiple Input Multiple Output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train an RNN to predict stock prices in the future.

My goal is to train the model using two datasets: X_train and y_train.

X_train is a 3D array including (number of observations, number of previous candles, attributes of each candle)

y_train is a 3D array including (number of observations, number of observations in the future, price).

So if I have data from 500 candles my X_train will be (430,60,6): for 430 observations (current candle each time) take the 60 observations that came before it and 6 characteristics (close price, volume, etc.) of them and try to use that data (through the RNN) to predict y_train(430, 10,1): for 430 observations predict the close price (corresponds to 1) for the next 10 candles.
I cannot, for the life of me, get the dimensions to enter the model correctly.
I use the following code for the model:

```
regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = ( 
X_train.shape[1], 6)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressor.add(LSTM(units = 1))

regressor.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 20, batch_size = 32)
```

I get `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lstm_6 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (430, 10, 1)`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: firstly, this stacked lstm structure is quite unusual for what you are doing to say the least.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's take a step back here and look at what is done and why it does not work.

Firstly, your input data is of the following shape:

```
(samples, timesteps, features)
```

Secondly, you would like your output data to be of the following shape:

```
(samples, future_timesteps, 1)
```

This kind of architecture is known as [sequence to sequence learning](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) (colloquially referred to as Seq2Seq).

So how do we do a Seq2Seq? There are a few ways you might want to read up on and this is still an area of very active research. Here are some ideas.

Note this is done with the [keras functional api](https://keras.io/models/model/). It is better.

Read the input sequence from both directions, then predict the next 30 units for pricing by having a final dense layer of 30 units.

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(600,6,))

lstm = Bidirectional(
    LSTM(250),
    merge_mode='concat'
)(input_layer)

pred = Dense(10)(lstm)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=pred)
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 20, batch_size = 32)
```

where `Y_train` is reshaped to `(430, 10)` instead of `(430, 10, 1)`. In response to a comment, this does not alter the labels (`Y_train`) in any meaningful way. This is because the difference between (x, y, 1) and (x,y) is just as follows:

```
[[[1],[2],[3]],
 [[4],[5],[6]]]
```

instead of

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6]]
```

So a call like:

```
Y_train = np.reshape(Y_train, Y_train.shape[:2])
```

does not meaningfully affect the training data.

However, this may not be the best architecture to begin with. This is because a single dense layer will be taking in the last hidden states from the forward and backward direction, instead of feeding every hidden state (from both directions) at every timestep. Effectively, the above model is unaware of more information presented in the below model. I suggest the following as an alternative.

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(600,6,))

encoder = Bidirectional(
    LSTM(250),
    merge_mode='concat',
    return_sequences=True
)(input_layer)
decoder = LSTM(250, return_sequences=True)(encoder)
pred = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(decoder)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=pred)
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 20, batch_size = 32)
```

where `Y_train` is formatted as `(430, 60, 1)`. If you only care about the next `10` entries, pass `sample weighting` into fit and weight everything after the `10th` time index as `0` (you can even populate it with garbage then if you want while training). This would be done as follows:

```
Y_train = np.hstack([Y_train]*6)
```

Then you would create a sample weight mask like:

```
W = np.zeros(Y_train.shape)
W[:,np.arange(W.shape[1]) < 10,:] = 1
```

That is, a mask where only the first 10 entries along the second axis are 1, and all others are zero. Pass this `W`, as the `sample_weights` parameter in `model.fit`

This way, the model can have a true sequence to sequence notion in the encoder/decoder paradigm.

Finally, it is not that additional LSTMS (stacking) is necessaraly bad, but it is regarded to be incremental at best in improving models of this nature, and does add a large amount of complexity as well as severely increasing training time. Get a single model to work with recurrent depths of 1 (no stacking), and then you can work on either stacking your single lstm or stacking encoders/decoders in the second structure I gave you.

Some additional tips for what you are doing:

- scale your data. StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, whatever. Do not pass raw price data into an LSTM (or any deep learning model) as the activation functions will smash these values to -1, 1, 0 whatever and you will be subject to the vanishing or exploding gradients problem.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailed answer. It really helped me move forward. I have some follow-up questions.
Why would a stacked LSTM RNN not work in this case?
On your first suggestion Y_train is reshaped to (430, 10) instead of (430, 10, 1). How can the RNN be trained if there are is no actual data, since the last dimension are the close prices we are interested in?
From what aspect is the second suggestion better?
Lastly an example in sample_weighting would be very much appreaciated.
Thanks a lot. I've been in a rut for days and I cannot express my gratitude for the help.

Comment: No worries. @PnerFlner I will add the answers to your question in my actual answer now.

Comment: Your answers have been of great help. Thanks a lot. Finally, do you have a resource to start over with Keras, be it a book, a series of videos or lecture? I have been learning from some online tutorials but they are insufficient to say the least.You can kick start some things the fast way, albeit at the expense of true understanding.

Comment: what does TimeDistributed do? and why does bi directional increase accuracy